# Cancel button in dialog not dismissing dialog

Tags: java, android, android-dialog

I have a dialog that I launch with:

```
// custom dialog
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);

        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.add_taste_dialog);

        dialog.setTitle("Add Taste");
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);


        Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

        Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);
        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
```

The problem is that when I click the button it does not dismiss the dialog.

My dialog xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tastePickTitle"
        android:text="Select a Taste: "
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle = "bold"
        android:padding="5dip"
        >
    </TextView>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/taste_array"

         />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp">
    </View>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ammountPickTitle"
        android:text="How much taste: "
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle = "bold"
        android:padding="5dip"
        >
    </TextView>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/ammount_array"

         />

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:layout_weight="1"
         />   


     <Button
        android:id="@+id/addTasteButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="addTasteNow" />




     </LinearLayout>




</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the full taste tag java code to give the snipet above some more context:

```
public class TasteTags extends Activity {

    BeerData e;



    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tastetag_page);

        //get beer data
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
        e = b.getParcelable("myBeerObject");

        TextView beerTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.beerTitleTaste);

        beerTitle.setText(e.beerName + " Taste Profile");

        String url = "myURL";

        url = url + "b=" +e.beerId;

        //async task to get beer taste tag percents
        new GetTasteJSON(this).execute(url);




    }

    public void addTaste(View v){

        // custom dialog
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);

        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.add_taste_dialog);

        dialog.setTitle("Add Taste");
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);


        Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

        Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);
        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("dialog", "cancel pressed");
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();


    }







}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the exactly code that you are running? Try to add `Toast` to make sure the button in really being clicked.

Comment: its not liking my toast: Toast.makeText(v,  "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: I put a log in there and it didnt come up when the cancel button was pressed.

Comment: can you post the content of your **add_taste_dialog** layout?

Comment: @AndersonSilva added the xml

Comment: make `final Dialog dialog = null;` a global variable (activity level), remove the `final` and initialize at it where you have it right now, that is fine.

Comment: I added all the code to give it more context. @LuckyMe I will give that a try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make `final Dialog dialog = null;` a global variable (activity level), remove the `final` and initialize at it where you have it right now, that is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code nothing jumps out, if you post your full code or a simple example to replicate i'm sure someone could fully decipher the problem.  I have included some sample snippets that show a dialog that work, take a look at those to see if they shed any insight as to why yours does not work.

One thing to check before looking at the working sample, make sure you don't have a button in your dialog view with id 'cancelButton' defined twice(common from copy/paste errors).  This will cause the behavior you are seeing.  If you take the working example below and use the following view it will reproduce your behavior:

Broken Dialog View

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:text="close" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:text="close" />
```

See below for working example.

Dialog View:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:text="close" />
```

Application class

```
package com.example.dialog;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);

    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

    dialog.setTitle("Add Taste");


    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}
```

}